# Syntax error: 'missing semicolon' when creating a MySQL trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

My trigger query:

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `test`.`users_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `users` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 UPDATE test.users
 SET enabled=1
    FROM Inserted i
    WHERE username = i.username
END
```

It complains about this part: `SET enabled=1`. I have tried adding quotes, didn't help.

Most likely the syntax is wrong, but I can't figure out what exactly is wrong here.

EDIT:

Or could it be done like this?

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `test`.`users_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `users` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 UPDATE test.users
 SET enabled=1
 WHERE username = NEW.username;
END
```

Comment: Where is alias i defined? (i.username)

Comment: I thought `Inserted` would be enough, just like `NEW`, now I have doubts. Could I use `NEW` instead?

Answer (score 1):

remove `from inserted` query:

```
delimiter | 
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `test`.`users_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `users` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 UPDATE test.users
 SET enabled=1
    WHERE username = i.username;
END
| 
delimiter ;
```